# google play store crashes

Tags: root-access, stock-android

Seems like impossible to fix:

I have a *ZTE Max* which I've rooted. I downloaded a ROM but didn't quite install it: just ran to recovery and hit factory reset, thinking it will just ask me for update to load. Anyways, I've rebooted the phone and when I click *Play store* it crashes immediately.

I tried enabling but nothing is disabled. Cleared data and cache for anything with "download" or "play store". Got agravated, removed the root and factory reset about 10 times after repeating the steps over and over again.

Also when I click to add a google account it doesn't respond. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: When you flashed your ROM, did you use the correct GApps package?

Comment: @HasH_BrowN from the description, OP didn't flash the ROM, but only did a factory-reset: "I downloaded a ROM but didn't quite install it: just ran to recovery and hit factory reset". But I might have misinterpreted that: If really flashed, a wrong version is the most likely reason indeed.

Comment: @Izzy Oops,  your right.  "Didn't quite install"

Answer (score 0):

Factory-resetting only wipes the user data. If you want to go back to the original ROM and unroot to fix your phone, you need to find the original ROM that your phone came with, and follow the procedure to flash it to your phone.

Comment: Thanks when i get home im going to try to flash a factory rom for my phone. Hopefully have play store back. And no just installed rom to phone but didnt flash it.